# C++ Boost::serialization "no matching function for call" to constructor of the class in my loading function's argument

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

My actual question is in the bold text below, but here's the context of my problem:

I'm trying out Boost::serialization for saving and restoring a player's state. I read the tutorial at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#simplecase, but I'm not sure how

```
boost::archive::text_iarchive
```

works.

I'm working on the assumption that the following lines

```
boost::archive::text_iarchive inArchive(playerfile);
    inArchive >> target;
```

will initialize the target according to the playerfile's corresponding textfile?

I'm wrote the following functions with that assumption:

```
bool SavePlayerState(Player *target)
{
std::string fileName = (target->name) + ".playerfile";
std::ofstream playerfile(fileName);

if(!playerfile.is_open())
{
    s_al_show_native_message_box(display, "SAVE FAILURE", "SAVE FAILURE", fileName + "could not be created/opened.",
                             NULL, ALLEGRO_MESSAGEBOX_ERROR);

    return false;
}

boost::archive::text_oarchive outArchive(playerfile);
outArchive << target;

return true;
}

bool LoadPlayerState(std::string playerName, Player *target)
{
std::string fileName = playerName + ".playerfile";
std::ifstream playerfile(fileName);

if(!playerfile.is_open())
{
    s_al_show_native_message_box(display, "LOAD FAILURE", "LOAD FAILURE", fileName + "could not be found/opened.",
                             NULL, ALLEGRO_MESSAGEBOX_ERROR);

    return false;
}

boost::archive::text_iarchive inArchive(playerfile);
inArchive >> target;

return true;
}
```

They are called in main() for testing purposes:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
//...

player = new Player(5,5); // There is a Player*player; declared elsewhere
LoadPlayerState("player", player); //Load the file with this name, target is player object
beings.push_back(player);

//The game's operations...

SavePlayerState(player);

delete player;

//...

return 0;
}
```

**SavePlayerState(player); works as I expected, and I find that player.playerfile has been created in my directory. But LoadPlayerState("player", player); gives me the following error:**

```
C:\Development\Libraries\boost\boost\serialization\access.hpp|132|error: no matching function for call to 'Player::Player()'|
```

**I don't know why the constructor should have problems, or why Save works and not Load. I'm not trying to make a new Player object, just shape the existing target Player according to the archive. What do I need to change in order to make this work?**

My player class:

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H_INCLUDED
#define PLAYER_H_INCLUDED

#include "being.h"
#include "extfile.h"

#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>

class Player: public Being
{
friend class boost::serialization::access;
template<class PlayerArchive>
void serialize(PlayerArchive & par, const unsigned int version)
{
    par & boost::serialization::base_object<Being>(*this);

    par & active;
    //par & various things
}

public:
Player(bool savedPlayer);
Player(int spawnXCell, int spawnYCell);
~Player();
//Functions
};

//Prototype to the save and Load state functions mentioned previously are found here.


#endif // PLAYER_H_INCLUDED
```

Here is my complete build messages log, if it helps:

```
>||=== Build: Debug in Roguelike (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
>C:\Development\Libraries\boost\boost\serialization\access.hpp||In instantiation of 'static void boost::serialization::access::construct(T*) [with T = Player]':|
>C:\Development\Libraries\boost\boost\serialization\serialization.hpp|93|required from 'void boost::serialization::load_construct_data(Archive&, T*, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_iarchive; T = Player]'|
>C:\Development\Libraries\boost\boost\serialization\serialization.hpp|158|required from 'void boost::serialization::load_construct_data_adl(Archive&, T*, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_iarchive; T = Player]'|
>C:\Development\Libraries\boost\boost\archive\detail\iserializer.hpp|341|required from 'void boost::archive::detail::pointer_iserializer::load_object_ptr(boost::archive::detail::basic_iarchive&, void*, unsigned int) const [with Archive = boost::archive::text_iarchive; T = Player]'|
>C:\Development\Projects\Roguelike\Roguelike\player.cpp|76|required from here|
>C:\Development\Libraries\boost\boost\serialization\access.hpp|132|error: no matching function for call to 'Player::Player()'|
>C:\Development\Libraries\boost\boost\serialization\access.hpp|132|note: candidates are:|
>C:\Development\Projects\Roguelike\Roguelike\player.cpp|8|note: Player::Player(int, int)|
>C:\Development\Projects\Roguelike\Roguelike\player.cpp|8|note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided|
>C:\Development\Projects\Roguelike\Roguelike\player.cpp|3|note: Player::Player(bool)|
>C:\Development\Projects\Roguelike\Roguelike\player.cpp|3|note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided|
>C:\Development\Projects\Roguelike\Roguelike\player.h|12|note: Player::Player(const Player&)|
>C:\Development\Projects\Roguelike\Roguelike\player.h|12|note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 5 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 4 second(s)) ===|
```

Thanks very much. If any other information is required, I will append it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear:

```
no matching function for call to 'Player::Player()'
```

You must have a default constructor in your class.

Comment: Oh, so it was right under my nose. I had always assumed that the default constructor exists, well, by default. Thanks!

Comment: @Itolet Read e.g. [this reference about default constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor), it will tell you when and why the compiler will not make a default constructor for you.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Joachim said, in some cases you will not be able to make a type default-constructible (especially when you're adding non-intrusive serialization to types from a 3rdparty library).

In that case learn about the `load_construct_data` customization point:

> **[Non-default Constructors](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#constructors)**

This mechanism is already automatically employed for you e.g. in the deserialization of STL containers whose element type has no default constructor.